# How to unit test a method which has CompletedFeature<UserDefinedObject>.supplyAsync(()-> someMethodWithReturn())) using Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, completable-future

I have a controller class with a method something() which makes calls to two different methods of the same class and merge the result of two calls.

```
class Controller{
  ...
  public UDC doSomething(){
    CompletableFuture<UDC> feature1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {this.doOther()}).exceptionally(ex -> {return new SomeException();});

    CompletableFuture<UDC> feature2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {this.doSomeOther()}).exceptionally(ex -> {return new SomeException();});
    ...
    return feature1.combine(feature2).get();

  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use Mockito to mock `CompletableFuture` here, any of them...

In the test, treat the Controller's `doSomething` functionality as a black box that given some input returns `UDC`.

Now, it's possible that `doOther` and/or `doSomeOther` call some external code that should be mocked. In this case the `Controller` looks probably something like this:

```
class Controller {
    private final SomeExternalDependency dependency1;

    public Controller(SomeExternalDependency dependency1) {
       this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    }

    private UDC doOther() {
      ... 
      dependency1.foo();
      ...
    }

    private UDC toSomeOther() {
      ...
      dependency1.bar();
      ...
    }
}
```

In this case in the test you can mock out the dependency1 with mockito as usual:

```
class MyTest {

   @Test 
   public void doSomething() {

      SomeExternalDependency dep = Mockito.mock(SomeExternalDependency.class);
      // specify the expectations
      Controller controller = new Controller(dep);

      controller.doSomething(); 

   }
}
```